# Conv A = Dual B

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, convex-optimization, convex-analysis

I have two cones $A$ and $B$ in a Euclidean space.
I want to show that $\mathrm{Conv}\,A=\mathrm{Dual}\,B$; that is, $a\in\mathrm{Conv}\,A$ if and only if $\langle a,b\rangle\ge 0$ for any $b\in B$.

The inclusion $\mathrm{Conv}\,A\subset \mathrm{Dual}\, B$ (or equivalently $\mathrm{Dual}\,A\supset \mathrm{Conv}\,B$) is easy --- one has to check $\langle a,b\rangle\ge 0$ for pairs $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.
It remains to show the opposite inclusion $\mathrm{Conv}\,A\supset \mathrm{Dual}\,B$. I see that in principle it can be done by calculations.

> Do you know tricks that help to prove the opposite inclusion $\mathrm{Conv}\,A\supset \mathrm{Dual}\,B$? Is there software that can help?

The cones $A$ and $B$ are very concrete; they are given by few algebraic identities and inequalities in $\mathbb R^{10}$.
(In principle I could describe the sets of vectors here, but I do not think it might help.)

Comment: I assume that $\operatorname{Conv} A$ denotes the convex hull of $A$? But why do you need to take the convex hull of a cone, given that a cone is already convex?

Comment: @JochenGlueck I did not say that cones are convex (in fact they are not).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! Hmm, may I suggest to include a definition of your usage of the word *cone* in the question? (I just browsed half a dozen books about ordered vector spaces; many of them define a *cone* indeed to be always convex, while some others do not - and there also seem to be some further differences between the various definitions of a *cone* in the literature).

Comment: @JochenGlueck a set $X$ is a cone if $v\in X$ implies that $\lambda{\cdot}v\in X$ for any $\lambda\ge0$.

Comment: Thank you very much.